# How to define many to many relationship between products and orders in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, relation

I have an *Order_product* table like this:

```
id
order_id
product_id
```

and a *products* table like this:

```
id
name
slug
price
```

how can I get the product name from the products table using `OrderProduct::where('order_id')` and show it to view?
and how to set the relationship?

Can somebody explain it for study purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is basically called many to many relationship. The table which has
> both order_id and product_id is known as pivot table.

you can find extensive documentation of relationship on Laravel official documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships. For your understanding you can define relationships as below.

**In Order Model:**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

**In Product Model:**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
}
```

**In Controller**

```
use App\Models\Product;

$products = Product::find(1);

foreach ($products->orders as $product) {
    //
}
```

**Filtering Relationship**

```
$product = Product::where('products.id', 1)
    ->with(['orders' => function($query) {
        // Order where condition goes here
        $query->where('orders.id', 1);
    }])
    ->first();

$product = Product::find(1)
    ->with(['orders' => function($query) {
        // Order where condition goes here
        $query->where('orders.id', 1);
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

create function in your Order Model

```
public function products() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class); 
}
```

*and in your view blade *

```
foreach($order->products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
}
```